# How do we calculate the types of balls after randomly removing 90% and then randomly adding 10% of the removed ones back?

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

I am trying to solve the following problem:

We have 1000 **types** of balls (different colour, size etc.) in Pool 1. Each type of ball is there 3 times (so 3000 balls in total). We now randomly remove 90% of all the balls from Pool 1, and put them into Pool 2. We now go to Pool 2, and randomly choose 10% of the balls in Pool 2 and put them back into Pool 1.

My question is: Is there a formula to calculate the number of **types** of balls now there in Pool 1?
I think that after the first step of removing balls from Pool 1, there should be $(1000 - 1000 * 0.9^3)$ types left, but I am not sure. I do not know how to incorporate the second step of adding random balls back in to the pool.

Bonus question: Is there a formula to calculate the number of types of balls in the second pool?

Comment: Is Pool 2 initially empty?  And are you looking for the mean number of types, or are you looking for the distribution of the number of types?

Comment: this is a problem I formulated, the actual scenario and context is slightly different, but I thought it is easier to abstract the problem.

Comment: Yes, Pool 2 is initially empty. I am looking for the mean number of types.

Comment: If just the former, if all selections are uniform, then you should be able to just treat it as having just removed (in one operation) the number of balls that are in Pool 2 at the end, if I understand the situation correctly.

Comment: yes, you are right! Thanks!

Comment: The poll 2 plays no role. Equally you can simly remove $81\%$ of balls and throw them away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing $90$% balls randomly and transferring them to Pool $2$ is equivalent to choosing $10$% balls to retain in Pool $1$.

Hence, the first step is to choose $300$ balls randomly from Pool $1$.

Its not hard to see that in the best case *(considering more number of types of balls in Pool $1$ as our favorable event)*, all $300$ balls to be retained must be of different types.

And, in the worst case, there must be $3$ balls of every type, which means we will have only $100$ different types of balls.

So there you have your upper and lower bounds for Pool $1$, that is $[100, 300]$

And, consequently for Pool 2, its $[700, 900]$

Now if you want arithmetic mean values, it follows directly. However, if you want the expected (probabilistic) value, it gets a little tedious.

To give you an idea of the approach, what you must do is consider each case separately and take the sum of all those cases weighted by their respective probabilities, the first few terms of which would look like this for Pool $1$: $$k= 300 \frac{^{1000}C_{300}}{^{3000}C_{300}} + 299 \frac{^{1000}C_{1}\times^{1000}C_{298}}{^{3000}C_{300}}+...$$

Can you continue from here?